# VBA division by

Tags: excel, vba, calculator, basic

I have problem with division by `0` in my VBA calculator. How can I get it to show a `MsgBox` `"U can't divise by 0"` when i try to divide by `0`?
There is my "=" and "/" code:

```
'equals button
Private Sub Wynik_Click() 'równa się
   var2 = TextBox1.Value
    xWynik = Application.Evaluate(var1 & var2)
    TextBox1.Value = xWynik
End Sub

'division
Private Sub Dziel_click()
    If var2 = "0" Then
        MsgBox ("Nie można dzielić przez 0")
    Else
        var1 = TextBox1.Value + "/"
        TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is a good check:

```
Public Sub DivByZero()
    If var2 = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("You cannot divide by 0")
    Else
        Var1 = textbox1.value / var2
    End If

End Sub
```

You can do it with an error-catcher as well, but it will be probably over complicating this small example:

```
Public Sub DivByZero()

    On Error GoTo DivByZero_Error
    Var1 = textbox1.value / var2

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

DivByZero_Error:

    MsgBox "Division by 0 or another error!"

End Sub
```

**Disclaimer:**
If you promise, that you will never write such code for the transport or for the medical industry, use this:

```
If var2 = "0" or len(trim(var2)) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Second one gives me ""Division by 0 or another error!" when I divise by every number. First gives me bug on equal "xWynik = Application.Evaluate(var1 & var2)" here

Comment: @GoldenRC - check your input variables. What is `var2`, what is `Var1`, where and how do you declare them, what is `textbox1.value`?

Comment: var1 and var2 are variables and textbox1.value is the value of display

Comment: Cool. What kind of variables are these? How are they defined?

Comment: Everyth is working without division by 0: https://pastebin.com/2pHe3L3A

Comment: @GoldenRC - try with the new thing :)

Comment: still in "xWynik = Application.Evaluate(var1 & var2)" I'm getting error when i try to division by 0

Comment: I don't have any idea still